Tor works only if SOCKS proxy is turned off. Why is that?
Yesterday I set up Tor to use Safari to access websites blocked in my country.
Step 1. brew install tor
Step 2. Safari > Settings > Advanced > Proxies: Change Settings > SOCKS proxy = On > Server = 127.0.0.1 > Port = 9050
Step 3. brew services start tor
It worked fine, but then, probably because I tried to start Tor using tor instead of brew services start tor, it stopped work.
Then I have discovered that if I skip Step 2, that is, if SOCKS proxy is turned off, Tor works once again.
Why is that? And how to "fix" it, that is, how to make Tor work if SOCKS proxy is turned on instead of off?
